# Using tune and ray.remote() in same python package

Tags: python, ray

I want to use a class of an own package for two purposes:

1. I want to use ray[tune] to find hyperparameters of an algorithm inside and
2. I want to have parallelized simulation runs (randomized environment).

For 2. I use ray.remote() as decorator for the class and instantiate it from a script file and call the remote object functions.
And for 1. I now comment ray.remote() and use ray.tune with a training function to let it instantiate an object and run it.

The point is, that in the first case tune is paralizing the job and in the 2nd case it is done using ray.remote().
Is there any way to combine both approaches without having to comment or uncomment the ray.remote() decorator?

Comment: maybe you should use `ray.remote()` as normal function, instead of as `decorator`. Most decorators can do this - something like `def func(): ...` and later `func = ray.remote(func)` or `func = ray.remote(args)(func)`

Comment: you maybe try to create two functions (with different names) which run your original function, and add decorator to one of your new functon - and then you can use first new function with `tune` and second new function as remote function.